# '91 Ranger Radio Circuit Board

Tags: ford, audio, wiring, ranger

I want to disable the tape deck from my '91 Ford Ranger factory stereo, and solder an AUX cable in its place. I took the radio apart, and to to get to the top of the board and find the labeled connections will require an extensive level of disassembly that I'm not sure I want to attempt. Is there any way to tell which pins are for the tape deck audio L/R outputs from the bottom of the board, pictured below?

Alternatively, is there another way to wire a AUX cord in to the factory stereo without disabling the radio, or having to rely on a radio transmitter?

Thanks for your time!

[image]

Comment: I'm definitely no expert, but I would bet if you followed the wires coming off the tape head, that's what you need to use to connect something like that to the stereo. It should include a left/right and ground to it, which should align directly with the plug you're trying to connect ... it may have a power lead as well ... see, I'm no expert ... try this at your own risk :o)

Comment: I always used one of these....https://www.amazon.com/MP3-Cassette-Player-Adapters/b?ie=UTF8&node=13981611

Comment: Found a video on wiring an AUX cable to the tape deck in a boom box, and learned there are orange and yellow (L/R) audio cables leading away from the gizmo that reads the magnetic symbol from the cassette tape. Sure enough, there were two matching cables coming from the little black box on this tape deck, so I snipped them, wired in the AUX cable, confirmed continuity.... AND THE TAPE STILL PLAYED THROUGH THE TRUCK SPEAKERS. In total there are 4 wires leading from that little black box, and cutting two of them did nothing. My mind is explode. Guess I'll try cutting the other two wires now?